# WP7 : Can't get Canvas.RenderTransform value

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have about 3-4 canvas controls and each contains about 750-1200 paths.
Users needs to make some transform to them and I use for that a global

```
    Canvas SelectedCanvas;
```

Initially (in the constructor) SelectedCanvas takes the value of one my canvas controls.

```
    SelectedCanvas = canvas1;
```

For the button wich rotates the canvas I use the next function:

```
    private void RotateRightLayerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedCanvas.RenderTransform != null)
        {
            //method 1
            CompositeTransform ct = canvas1.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
            if (ct.Rotation == 360)//ct will return NullException
                ct.Rotation = 0;
            ct.Rotation += 30;

            // method 2
            TransformGroup tg = canvas1.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;                
            (tg.Children[0] as RotateTransform).Angle += 30;
            //tg will return NullException                               
        }
    }
```

I also tried [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/578a058e-75ac-4550-b4be-18cf9569cf5e/) and
[this link](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/602405-wpf-rotate-canvas)
but I need also to get the value of `RenderTransform`.
Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So which transform have you set on your Canvas? It is [Transform.Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.identity.aspx) by default.

Comment: I use `RotateTransform` because I want to rotate the canvas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property is [Transform.Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.identity.aspx). You have to apply a Transform, e.g. a RotateTransform, to your Canvas before you can manipulate it.

If you use a RotateTransform your code would have to look like this:

```
RotateTransform t = bd1.RenderTransform as RotateTransform; 
if (t.Angle >= 360) 
    t.Angle = 0; 
t.Angle += 30;
```

or:

```
RotateTransform t = bd1.RenderTransform as RotateTransform; 
t.Angle = (t.Angle + 30) % 360;
```