# Elementhosted WPF-Mediaelement does not allow rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, mediaelement

I am having a windows forms app.

I want to use a mediaelement in it, so I use the elementhost. I create a wpf usercontrol in which I put a mediaelement. In my app I write the following having the goal in mind to rotate the element.

```
System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement wm = new 
System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement();
wm.LayoutTransform.Value.Rotate(22.0);
elementHost1.Child = wm;
wm.Source = new Uri(dateiname);
wm.Play();
```

dateiname is the filename.

It plays but it is not rotated. How to rotate wm's video?

Comment: does it work in pure WPF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166546/wp7-cant-get-canvas-rendertransform-value helped.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little later. Try this:

```
        RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform {Angle = 20.0};
        wm.LayoutTransform = rt;
```